# What is the Infinite Squirrel deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've heard of the Infinite Squirrel Deck, and it looks as though it revolves around [Earthcraft](https://scryfall.com/card/tmp/222/earthcraft) and [Squirrel Nest](https://scryfall.com/card/mh1/182/squirrel-nest).

**Is this the only distinguishing feature of an Infinite Squirrel deck?**

Comment: @Pat, I don't understand why you would use your mod powers to reopen a question that the community voted to close, and then use your mod powers to erase the comments explaining why. In any case, it was closed for good reasons and I have restarted the close vote.

Comment: @Rainbolt A lot of those comments were obsolete because of the question change. Granted mod reopens can be pretty unpleasant if you're on the closing side. But now I get to have an answer to a legitimate question I want to see answered, so I'm happy.

Comment: @Rainbolt It might've been better if there were an explanatory note after deleting the comments, but I think deleting them and reopening makes sense: the close votes and all that discussion were based on a different form of the question, and it's really hard to get enough votes to reopen things here whether or not they deserve it. If people *still* want to close it in this form, fair enough, but it does seem to be answerable if unexciting.

Comment: @doppelgreener *Some* comments were obsolete. Some still apply to the current form of the question.

Comment: @Rainbolt - I voted my conscience.  The question, in its current state is valid.  We should welcome questions that seek understanding and be eager to give it willingly.  It is not required that all questions be geared for an expert.  If you have questions about this, please take it to [meta]

Comment: Dead links. :(.

Comment: @Joshua undead links

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your assessment is correct.  The infinite squirrel deck revolves around the two card combo.  This leaves 52 cards of the deck open to design choices.  Consequently, there's a huge variety of infinite squirrel decks.  This variety is greatly affected by the local meta game.